# Im trying to delete a row without changing page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<?php
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_BOTH)) 
          {
            $id= $_POST['tran_no'];;
        ?>

              <tbody>
                  <tr id=<?php echo $row['trans_no']?>>
                    <td><?php echo $row['trans_no']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['obj_code']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['div_no']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['check_no']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['payee']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['payment']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['add']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['amount']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['amountw']?></td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="#" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="delete" title="Delete"><img src="image/remove.png"></a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

        <?php
      }
      ?>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
      <script src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
      $(".delete").click(function(){
      var element = $(this);
      var del_id = element.attr("trans_no");
      var info = 'trans_no=' + del_id;
      if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))
        {
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "delete.php",
          data: info,
          success: function(){
        }
        });
          $(this).parents(".show").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
          .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
        }
      return false;
        });
        });
      </script>
```

My problem is the ajax code doesnt seem to delete the row i dont know if the ajax code is executed or not. help would be much need, and please give me an insight as to what is the problem with my code or if i have to add something. heres the delete.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root"," ","dole") or die("Could not connect database");
if($_POST['trans_no'])
{
$id=$_POST['trans_no'];
$delete = "DELETE FROM table_no WHERE trans_no = '$id'";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$delete);
}

?>
```

Comment: If you check the console you'll see the result of the AJAX request to determine if it was sent, and if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1:**

You are assigning id from database to `id` attribute and in AJAX, reading `trans_no`.

`trans_no` attribute is not set for the delete link.

That is why you are not getting it.

Change your HTML to

```
<a href="#" trans_no="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="delete" title="Delete"><img src="image/remove.png"></a>
```

To make it HTML5 Compliant:

```
<a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="delete" title="Delete"><img src="image/remove.png"></a>
```

And change JS:

```
var del_id = element.attr("data-id");
```

**OPTION 2**

Just change the line:

```
var del_id = element.attr("trans_no");
```

To

```
var del_id = element.attr("id");
```

And use your existing code.

It will work.

Comment: Do not use `trans_no`, use `data-id` instead.

Comment: `var del_id = element.data("id");` will also read the contents of attribute `data-id`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$(function() {
  $(".delete").click(function(){
     var element = $(this);         
     var transNoVar = element.attr('id');

     if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))
     {
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "delete.php",
            data: {
                trans_no: transNoVar
            },
            success: function(data){
                // delete.php return 1 on success 0 otherwise, check it here
                if(data=='1') {
                    // on success hide the tr
                    // add class="show" to the tr
                    $(this).parents(".show").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
      .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
                } else {
                    alert('Error deleting your record');
                }
            }
        });          
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: i tried your code but it returns  alert('Error deleting your record');

Comment: check what you're returning from the php code. Is it '1' or 1, it's going to else based on your return value. @newbie

Comment: so my codes are sending string rather than integer?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
   var element = $(this);
   var del_id = this.id;// use this.id as your database id related to element id
   var info = {trans_no : del_id};
   if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?")){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete.php",
        data: info,
        success: function(data){
            if(data=='success'){
                 // hide only in case of successful deltion
                 element.parents(".show").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
                  .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
            } else {
                alert('Error while deleting');
            }
        }
      });          
   }
   return false;
});
```

And in PHP return `success` or `error` like,

```
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root"," ","dole") or die("Could not connect database");
  $status='error';
  if(isset($_POST['trans_no']) && $_POST['trans_no']){
     $id=$_POST['trans_no'];
     $delete = "DELETE FROM table_no WHERE trans_no = '$id'";
     $res=mysqli_query($con,$delete);
     if($res){// only success in case of deleted.
        $status='success';
     }
  }
  echo $status;
?>
```

Comment: returns alert('Error while deleting');

Comment: it does not seem to execute the delete.php

Comment: @newbie check your console for debug.